# App Inventor - How to fill listpicker element with Google Spreadsheet query

Tags: app-inventor, listpicker

I'm trying to query a Google Spreadsheet with its API and fill the results into `listpicker` elements. Unfortunately I do not get any result and no error message. It just happens nothing.

When I call the `notifier` with the result it is showing the right ones and also when I use the spreadsheets API directly through the browser I see the right results. But in App Inventor it is not filling the Listpicker Elements. 
I hope you can help me.

[Here is an Image of my App Inventor Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdWLH.png)
[image]

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the red warning in the `Web.GotText` event, **else that block will not fire!**
And check, if the URL is correct, see also [my example here](https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php#select).

Also you are selecting 1 column, which means, you get back a 1 column csv table as result... which means, you should use the split block and split at `\n` (new line) to convert the result into a list instead of using the `list from csv row` block...

[image]

Comment: hey taifun, the warning is just because I have tried a lot and did not rename all the blocks correctly. But of course I did for testing, but that wasnt working at all. It is also correct, that there is only one column which is chosen but I do not get how to split the block AND split also on new line. could you explain any further? (german will be also accepted as language)

Comment: dude, you rock. awesome. that was the solution. thanks a lot